# Is it possible to create Access Control for Azure Container Registry based on {repository:tag}?

Tags: azure-container-registry

I am familiar and have successfully tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-repository-scoped-permissions#feedback .

But what I really want is to define ACLs for a user of the container registry based on 'repository:tag'.

e.g. If I have
repo-A with tags v18.03 and v19.10, and
repo-B with tags v18.05 and v19.12

I want to be able to say a user is only allowed to pull repo-A:v19.10 and repo-B:v19.12 .

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it only supports to authenticate on the repository level currently and is a preview version. So you cannot authenticate on the tag level. Maybe it will support in the future, but now it doesn't support it.